# Значение overflow x y меняется на auto при задании только одной из координат CSS

Tags: css, overflow

Споткнулся о следующее поведение параметра `overflow`:

Если значение `overflow-x` любое кроме `initial`, `inherit`, или `unset` то значение `overflow-y` уже не будет прежним, а поменяться на `auto`.

Это мне очень сильно жизнь подпортило, если кто знает, что можно тут придумать говорите не молчите :)

[Ссылка на CodePen](https://codepen.io/nvrngrek/pen/dyGQGzZ)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#one td, #two td {
  max-width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 17px 10px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

#table td:hover {
  overflow-x: overlay;
  text-overflow: initial;
}

td::after {
  content: "";
  width: 99px;
  height: 10px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  left: -1px;
  bottom: -7px;
  cursor: n-resize;
  z-index: 999;
}

#one td {
  z-index: 2;
}

#two td {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <tr id="one">
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique, eligendi?</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="two">
    <td>two</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Красная полоска подразумевается для resize'a ячеек и нужно разкомментировать `overflow` чтобы понять суть проблемы.

Answer (score 2):

Из вопроса совершенно непонятно, что ты хочешь сделать, так что только про overflow.

`visible` может быть только одновременно по двум осям. Если хотя бы по одной из них ты ставишь что-то другое, то в такой комбинации оно работать не будет. Весьма вероятно, что в такой ситуации вместо `visible` используется `auto`. Однако, можно как угодно комбинировать `scroll`, `hidden`, `auto` и даже `overlay`, который снова поддерживается хромом.

Вполне возможно, поможет оборачивание в дополнительный контейнер, либо вынесение чего-то в отдельный элемент или псевдоэлемент.

Comment: @Vasily, @Qwertiy♦, да, вот этого я и боялся что здесь ничего нельзя поделать и придётся менять структуру, там просто тонна кода с логикой на d3 с этими таблицами написано и придётся вникать, спасибо ребят :)

Answer (score 1):

Дефолтное значение параметра [overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) это `visible`, независимо от того используете ли Вы `overflow-x`, `overflow-y`, или просто `overflow`.

Значение `overlay` из Вашего примера не стандартизировано и официально поддерживается только Webkit браузерами.

Если Вы испытываете некорректное поведение данного параметра с определенным(и) браузерам(и), то стоит указывать требуемое Вам значение explicitly.

Пример использования:

```
div {
   overflow-x: hidden;
   overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: Ещё `overflow` принимает два параметра `overflow: overflow-x overflow-y`.

Comment: @Vasily, спасибо за интерес и потраченное время на мою задачу.
В предложенном Вами решении, пропадает красная полоска, которая предназначена для resize'а. А в ней и в скроллинге не поместившегося текста в ячейку. Даже сейчас дополню ховерами, чтобы было красиво

Comment: @ Yoba Fighter Я поправил свой ответ, более точно указав я всего лишь привел пример указания обоих параметров. Что бы не быть уверенным в требуемом Вам результате, я, как и в своем ответе, рекомендую прописывать оба параметра даже если Вам нужно изменить только один.